# range out of bounds size 4 objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsrangeexception

I have an `NSString` of `length` 4. Logically, this should work, and `expYear` does, but `expMonth` throws an out of bounds exception?

```
expYear = [expDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
expMonth = [expDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 3)];
```

Comment: Read the docs for `NSMakeRange`.

Comment: You are obviously super helpful

Comment: I was serious. For a question like this all you needed to do was read the reference docs for `NSMakeRange` and you would have seen what the 2nd parameter means. Given the number of down votes, others seem to agree with me. The answer you accepted basically repeats what is in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A range is a `location` and a `length`, not a start and end position.

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
    NSUInteger location;
    NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

So with a start location of `2` and a length of `3` you overrun the end.

Change the range based on the correct specification.

Comment: You don't say whether you do, but you should also have a length check before running this code.

Answer (score 4):

The range doesn't mean from let's say 2 to 3 it's say start from 2 and go next 3 indexes so in this example you end up with 2-5, so this line is out of bounds:

```
expMonth = [expDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 3)];
```